# What is the state of the wider world in 2052?

Tags: dark

In the future, Winden has suffered some kind of cataclysmic accident, referred the apocalypse, which has partially destroyed a number of buildings and killed those inhabitants who weren't in some bunker.

What is the state of Germany as a whole, to say nothing of those regions beyond it, in this future? One would think that something that wasn't even energetic enough to destroy all the buildings or kill the people in a bunker well within the blast radius wouldn't have much effect outside of Winden. On the other hand, it *is* called the apocalypse.

The state of the survivors seems ambiguous too: On the one hand, they seem to be in bad shape, and one wouldn't think that people would be scrounging for scraps in the wreckage of Winden if there were less-damaged areas, although they do seem to have "religious" reasons to hang around. On the other hand, they're driving around in a tank and wearing military uniforms, which would seem a bit weird for random people, and suggests a functioning government.  And there was that rather large drone flying overhead in the first glimpse of the future at the end of the first season, which definitely doesn't suggest a population of scavengers struggling to survive.

So what is the state of the rest of the world after this apocalyptic event?

Comment: Not having heard of a work isn't a reason for close votes. That's part of why tags exist. If you couldn't figure out what show it was "unclear what you're asking" would be more appropriate in any case.

Comment: If you haven't heard of Dark, the correct solution is to go on Netflix and binge watch both seasons immediately.

Comment: @Adamant it wouldn't hurt using its name in your question, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not good. Shortly after the event, we see catastrophic events on a global scale such as extreme weather, tidal waves, failing electrical systems, leading to plane crashes and failing nuclear power plants.

In the second episode of the third season "The Survivors", we hear a radio in the abandoned Winden police station, about 2 months after the apocalypse:

> [Radiosprecherin]: "Wissenschaftler suchen nach Antworten auf die Ereignisse des 27. Juni 2020.
> Als Ursprungsregion der globalen Katastrophe gilt weiterhin die Kleinstadt Winden.
> Französische Forscher nehmen an, dass am 27. Juni unsere Welt für den Nanobruchteil einer Sekunde stillgestanden hat. Als Folge könnten die Gezeitenkräfte auseinandergelaufen sein, was eine Erklärung für die globalen Springfluten, Wetterphänomene und Störungen in elektrischen Systemen sein könnte, welche wiederum das Abstürzen von Flugzeugen erklären würde sowie die Unterbrechung des Stroms
> in Kernkraftwerken weltweit.
> Derweil ist eine Stabilisierung der Lage nicht..."
>
> —*Dark*, S3E2: "Die Überlebenden"

That translates to

> [woman on radio]: "Scientists are still looking for an explanation for the events of June 27, 2020.
> The the small town of Winden is still considered to be the point of origin for the catastrophe.
> A French team of scientists believes it possible that our world stood still for a fraction of a nanosecond on June 27th, possibly causing the divergence of tidal forces. This would explain the global tidal waves, weather phenomena and disturbances of electrical systems, which in turn could explain the countless number of airplane crashes and the simultaneous electrical outages at nuclear power plants worldwide.
> Meanwhile, stabilization of the situation is not..."

What we see of 2052 gives no indication that the situation *has* stabilised. The area around the nuclear plant is in the hands of a violent gang, led by Elisabeth. Heretics are executed.

While people living in nuclear exclusion zones like the one around Tsjernobyl is not unheard of, this kind of behaviour would — under normal circumstances — make the authorities come in to put an end to it. The fact that they don't, shows us that Germany doesn't have a government that is in control. From that, we can infer that at the very least, the other countries of the EU are in a similar shape.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this is a rather thin answer, but based upon what has been shown up to the end of season 2, I think that the answer is:

**Unpleasant.**

I am basing this on the following observations:

- The survivors that we see appear to belong to violent gangs.
- As you stated, large aerial vehicles have been shown cruising the skies, but it is not clear they cared about the survivors (and if they did, that they wouldn't just belong to a stronger power that poses a threat rather than being helpful in any way).
- At several points when the future of 2052 is shown, one of the telltale signs is that we can faintly hear the rattling of machine gun fire or explosions at a distance. This could point to even hotter warzones a couple of kilometres away than where the scavengers are living.

With that said, it is indeed not clear whether these circumstances are directly caused by the blast itself, or whether civilization has, to some extent, broken down step by step in the months following the "apocalypse" event.